# Javascript/Jquery : How do I pause each background color for 5 seconds during background loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var colors = Array('#2a83bd', '#982426', '#088C51', '#CADB1B');
var color_index = 0;
var interval = 1000;  // transition speed

function tbc_fadebg() {
    $('#topbanner_container').animate({ backgroundColor: colors[color_index] }, interval, 'linear', function() {
        if(color_index == colors.length) { color_index = 0; } //If we are at the end of the colors array go back to the beginning.
        else { color_index++; } //Lets move to the next color in the colors array.
        tbc_fadebg();
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if( $(window).width() > 1024 ) {
        tbc_fadebg();
    }
});
```

Above is my code.  How do I pause each background color for 5 seconds during this background loop and where do I place the code?  I've tried to set the timeout, but apparently I've done it wrong and can't figure out where to place it in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `setInterval()`, remove that `recursive` call,

```
var colors = Array('#2a83bd', '#982426', '#088C51', '#CADB1B');
var color_index = 0;
var interval = 1000;  // transition speed

function tbc_fadebg() {
    $('#topbanner_container').animate({ backgroundColor: colors[color_index] }, interval, 'linear', function() {
        if(color_index == colors.length) { color_index = 0; } //If we are at the end of the colors array go back to the beginning.
        else { color_index++; } //Lets move to the next color in the colors array.
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if( $(window).width() > 1024 ) {
        setInterval(tbc_fadebg,5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: that works, except it delays the function from firing right away.  Is there a way to make it fire immediately when page is loaded, and then the interval starts?

Comment: @kdjernigan Just make that function call before we start that interval. Let me know if that works for you. :)

Comment: What do you mean make the function call before setting interval?

Comment: Just call that function before that `setInterval()` invocation.

Comment: You mean, `tbc_fadebg(); setInterval(tbc_fadebg,5000);` right? Sorry, wording and layout of jquery are still new to me.

Comment: @kdjernigan No problem, Actually i meant that. :)

Comment: alright, by using `tbc_fadebg(); setInterval(tbc_fadebg,5000);` it is now working correctly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could have the `setTimeout()` before calling the function again.

```
function tbc_fadebg() {
    $('#topbanner_container').animate({ backgroundColor: colors[color_index] }, interval, 'linear', function() {
        if(color_index == colors.length) { color_index = 0; } //If we are at the end of the colors array go back to the beginning.
        else { color_index++; } //Lets move to the next color in the colors array.
        setTimeout(tbc_fadebg, 5000); // I added here, when calling the function again
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I decided to go with the setInterval() approach over setTimeout because of some issues I've faced in the past with setTimeout and fading backgrounds.